# Tell windows' scheduled task to run from now

Tags: windows, scheduled-tasks

I have created a scheduled task in Windows Server 2003 to run every minute. The start time is set to 12:00 AM so it will run all day. The start date is set to past date. The problem is the 'next run time' is shown to be tomorrow 12:00 AM. Is it possible to set it to run from now?

If I set start time to a few minutes after current time, it will run from that time, but tomorrow it will not run from 12:00 AM until the specified time right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scheduler has hit 12:00 AM and the task ran every minute, **but only for an hour**, which coincide with the **duration** of the task. So I misunderstood *duration*, at first I thought duration is:

```
how long the system will let the task run
and if the task is still running after the specified duration, terminate it.
```

Which is wrong. It turned out duration is:

```
for how long you want to keep calling the task on and on.
```

So I set duration to 24 hours, start time is still 12:00 AM, repeat task is still set to every 1 minute, and my task ran in the next minute just like I want.

Answer (score 4):

Set start time as `12:00 AM` as is.

After setting the time, `Right click` on the Task and select `Run`.

By this way, you can `Run` the task for `now` and also your scheduled task will run at your `expected time`.

In `Advanced Schedule Options`, you have a option saying `Repeat Task` --> `Every 10 minutes`

Choose that for repetitive running a task

Comment: Using the 'run' command only run it once, 'next run time' is still showing tomorrow 12:00 AM. Is it possible to tell it to just start with the specified schedule (every minute)?

Comment: @EndyTjahjono: You have a option `Repeat Task` under `Advanced Schedule Options`

Comment: I have set the task to run every minute like I said in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a trigger to run the task at creation/modification then under advanced set it to repeat every whatever number of minutes. Use the drop down box to switch from on schedule to task creation/modification.